# NodeJS issue with MongoDB: DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using expressjs framework of nodejs with MongoDB. 
When I'm running query then I'm getting this issue:-

```
(node:29411) DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
```

I'm using **MongoDB 4.0** version.

And there is my query which I'm executing

```
User
    .findByIdAndUpdate(item._id, {name: "Test name"}, function (err, user) {

    if (err || !user) {
        return res.status(401).json({ errors: "Invalid User." });
    }

    return res.render('view', {
        error: error,
        info: info,
        message: message,
        item: user
    });

});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using? Are you completely sure that the warning happens on that line? A bit more info would be nice.

Comment: I'm using mongoose `5.1.6` version

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warnings are as a result of changes in the MongoDB Node.js driver. Mongoose provides options for working around them.

Concerning the deprecation warning on the collection.findAndModify function, according to the Mongoose API [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html), since the Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() predates the MongoDB driver's findOneAndUpdate(), Mongoose uses the MongoDB driver's findAndModify() by default. That findAndModify() has now been deprecated and that's why you're getting the warnings.

You can set Mongoose to use the MongoDB driver's findOneAndUpdate() function instead by setting the useFindAndModify() global function to false. It is true by default.

Do this:

```
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false)
```

This will solve it. You should know that you can also pass this through the mongoose connection options.